# PN532 + UART connection direct to Android phone without Arduino Uno or Raspbery Pi

Tags: android, pn532

I'm trying to use PN532 for nfc to read/write Mifare tags. i want to connect Pn532 to Android phone via otg. and from Android application i want to control by PN532. so I want to know how to communicate / integrate Android with this board
without using Uno or pi microcontroller boards.